# Multiple Hashmaps into one. Java

Tags: java, android, google-maps, arraylist, hashmap

I have the following code that works but how can I do it shorter if there is any way. I will explain it in depth.

I have these three declared as global:

```
private Map<Marker, String> pictureinfo = new HashMap<Marker, String>();
private Map<Marker, String> latitudeinfo = new HashMap<Marker, String>();
private Map<Marker, String> longitudeinfo = new HashMap<Marker, String>();
```

I have a method called markers() that has a pretty big code, but somewhere in the code, I have:

```
pictureinfo.put(marker, poza);
latitudeinfo.put(marker, latitude + "");
longitudeinfo.put(marker, longitude + "");
```

poza, latitude and longitude are taken from a database, but that is irrelevant. And further in the code, I have a custom infowindow for multiple markers where I have:

```
String picture = pictureinfo.get(marker);
latcoord.setText(latitudeinfo.get(marker));
lngcoord.setText(longitudeinfo.get(marker));
```

How can I shorten these lines? The code works but I am sure there is another way, shorter and optimal. I don't have much experience wish HashMaps and ArrayLists so any guidance will be appreciated, I want to learn, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a wrapper object that has the info fields and then store those wrappers in a single map.

However, I'd not bother too much with such optimizations, there might be not much gain in it.

What I would do (although that's just one way):

```
class LocationInfo {
   private String latitudeInfo;
   private String longitudeInfo;     
   ...
}

class PictureInfo {      
  private String description; //I assume that's what pictureInfo means
  private LocationInfo locInfo;
  ...
}

Map<Marker, PictureInfo> infoMap = ...;
```

I'm not sure about the exact semantics of your code so this is just a crude approximation. Basically I'd put information on a location into one class, since that's not necessarily picture-specific. Depending on the semantics `LocationInfo` could also contain the location itself - in which case I'd name the class `Location`. (Btw, you're putting `latitude + ""` etc. so I assume you originally have primitive numbers. If that's the case then I'd store them unconverted in the `LocationInfo` class).

`PictureInfo` then contains a description, its own `LocationInfo` and whatever else it needs. Then you'd just store `PictureInfo` instances in your map. (If `Marker` is only used for `PictureInfo`, it could also be a member of that class).

As you can see the code probably doesn't get shorter, but often shorter is not better since the code might be harder to understand and to maintain. Often you'd want more structure in your code, e.g. by encapsulating related data into meaningful classes etc.

Comment: I will take that into a consideration but for my own good, I want to learn how to do that, can you elaborate your post?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure of your purposes, but from first sight this code hurts object orientedness. Data you hold in the maps seemingly strongly connect to a certain Marker object, and should be in it.

```
class Marker{
    ....

    String pictureInfo;
    String latitude;
    String longitude;

    ...
}
```

Instead of this:

```
pictureinfo.put(marker, poza);
latitudeinfo.put(marker, latitude + "");
longitudeinfo.put(marker, longitude + "");
```

this:

```
marker.setPictureInfo(poza);
marker.setLatitudeInfo(String.valueof(latitude));
marker.setLongitudeInfo(String.valueof(longitude));


String picture = marker.getPictureInfo();
latcoord.setText(marker.getLatitudeInfo());
lngcoord.setText(marker.getLongitudeInfo());
```